# Is it safe to grab the address of a struct field for using in a C program (even though there's some padding in the struct )?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, padding

Consider this little program :

```
//size of struct Test is 8 Bytes ( 3 Bytes padding )

struct Test{

    int a;
    char b;
}

struct Test t1;
t1.a = 30;
t1.b = 'R';

int* p = &(t1.a);
char* p2 = &(t1.b);

*p = 200;
*p2 = 'H';
```

1. Is it 100% safe to grab the addresses of struct fields and then use them to access these fields ?
2. What are some bad practices we should avoid when dealing with structs and pointers ?

Comment: Yes. Safe (assuming no other issues). And you don't need the parentheses. It's usually spelled without them (`&t1.a`).

Comment: Yes, it's 100% safe.

Comment: Petr Skocik, what do you mean by "other issues" ?

Comment: @alessiosolari Mainly strict aliasing violations, out of bound accesses, and racy accesses from multiple threads.

Comment: @PetrSkocik how can you access struct outside its bonds?

Comment: @0___________ Some structs have array members.

Comment: Whether the struct representation has any padding has little direct relevance to anything.  C has no rules discriminating between structs with padding and those without.

Comment: You can take an address of any object whatsoever and use it as long as said object exists. A struct field is not special in any way. (Unless it's a bit field, but  you cannot take an address of a bit field anyway, so there is no question of safety). Of course you should use any pointer correctly, but this has nothing to do with whether it points to a struct field or not.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it 100% safe to grab the addresses of struct fields and then use
> them to access these fields ?

Yes, it is as member of the struct has the same type as pointer. The compiler will calculate the correct reference.

> What are some bad practices we should avoid when dealing with structs
> and pointers ?

A very broad question. Generally do not do [pointer punning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning) and remember that binary representation of the struct  (if for example sent to another system) can be different on that system. In this case always serialize.

Comment: 0__________, what do you mean by pointer punning ? Could you give me an example ?